# Handling `NameError` without raising `SyntaxError` when referencing global variables in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, decorator

## Handling a `NameError` is raising a `SyntaxError`:

So I'm making a decorator function which associates a generator-function to a dictionary, with the intention of making the `send()` function less cumbersome to use.

The default behavior is to use a dictionary named `global_registry_dict` defined in (surprise!) the global-namespace.

If `global_registry_dict` does not exist and an alternative dictionary is not explicitly passed in, `NameError` is raised by python.

When I try to handle the error by creating the variable in the global namespace, I get a `SyntaxError` telling me that the variable is referenced before assignment. That makes sense...but...like...that's what I'm trying to fix!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Source for the Decorator:

```
def make_stateless_actor(func):
    def wrapper(registry_dict=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if registry_dict is None:
                internal_registry_dict = global_registry_dict
            elif isinstance(registry_dict, dict) or issubclass(registry_dict, dict):
                internal_registry_dict = registry_dict
            else:
                internal_registry_dict = global_registry_dict
        except NameError: # <<== CATCHES IF `global_registry_dict` IS REF'D BUT NOT DEFINED. 
            global global_registry_dict # <<== SYNTAX ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            global_registry_dict = {}
            internal_registry_dict = global_registry_dict
        gen = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(gen)
        internal_registry_dict[func.__name__] = gen
    return wrapper
```

## Exception Returned:

```
File "C:/yall/dont/need/to/know/this/generator_pipeline_utils.py", line 74
global global_registry_dict
^
SyntaxError: name 'global_registry_dict' is used prior to global declaration
```

## Source of the Entire Module:

```
# global_registry_dict = {}


def make_stateless_actor(func):
    """
    DESCRIPTION:
    ===========
    This DECORATOR FUNCTION simplifies & centralizes the use of `send()` on generators.

    It does this by ASSOCIATING the decorated function to a dictionary:

        - by default, a global variable named `global_registry_dict` will be used.
        - by default, `global_registry_dict = {}` will be created in the GLOBAL-NAMESPACE if it does not exist.

    IMPORTANT NOTE:
    ==============
    Use the `registry_dict` kwarg to manually assign your generator-func to an alternate dictionary:
            `foo_decorated_func(registry_dict=foo_alternative_dictionary)`

    REQUIREMENTS:
    ============
    You can apply `@make_stateless_actor` to any GENERATOR FUNCTION which:

        - INCLUDES A `yield` expression to the RIGHT of an `=` sign.
        - INCLUDES `**kwargs` as a function argument.
    """
    def wrapper(registry_dict=None, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if registry_dict is None: # <<-- necessary to prevent the next elif from throwing an exception.
                internal_registry_dict = global_registry_dict
            elif isinstance(registry_dict, dict) or issubclass(registry_dict, dict):
                internal_registry_dict = registry_dict
            else:
                internal_registry_dict = global_registry_dict
        except NameError:
            print('WARNING: global_registry_dict IS NOT DEFINED AND YOU DID NOT EXPLICITLY PASS registry_dict TO THE DECORATED FUNCTION.\n\
                  `global_registry_dict = {}` has been instantiated in the global-namespace.\n')
            global global_registry_dict
            global_registry_dict = {}
            internal_registry_dict = global_registry_dict
        gen = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(gen)
        internal_registry_dict[func.__name__] = gen
    return wrapper

@make_stateless_actor
def printer(*args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        item = yield
        print("Got: ", item)

def send(name, msg, registry_dict=None):
    if registry_dict is None:
        global_registry_dict[name].send(msg)
    else:
        registry_dict[name].send(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    printer(registry_dict=None) #<<==BEGIN THE CRAZY.
    # send('printer', 'HEY WHAT IS UP?')
    # send('printer', 666)
    # send('printer', [1, 'a', [], True])
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the name `global_registry_dict` in the `else` clause a couple lines up. If it's to be global, you must declare it so before using it, just as the error message says. Generally, names are declared global at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I could add a check at the beginning, but I guess I should clarify: Is there no way to instantiate a global variable after using `except` to find out that it doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Yes. Do what you're doing, except move the `global` declaration above the first use of the name, like I just said.

Comment: Lol. yep. Thanks.